# How do you convert a PriorityQueue to a List in the sorted order?

Tags: java, list, priority-queue

How do you convert a `PriorityQueue` to a `List` in the sorted order without altering (`poll(), etc`) the `PriorityQueue`? We want to keep both the `PriorityQueue` and the `List`.

Adding 2, 3, 1 to a `PriorityQueue` will sort it to 1, 2, 3. Creating an `ArrayList` from the `PriorityQueue` will have an order of 2, 3, 1. The `iterator()` and `toArray()` methods from the `PriorityQueue` will also have an order of 2, 3, 1. I guess it has to do with the implementation of `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: Docs say `iterator` doesn't return in any particular order. Maybe you'll have to iterate and sort again?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way is to poll the queue until it is empty and add each item to a list, or just add them all to a list, and then sort the list using the natural order or the same comparator as the priority queue.

Comment: Look's like an XY problem? To begin with, can you explain why can't you use remove elements from the queue? FYI elements inside the `PriorityQueue` are not stored in any order and similarly its iterator doesn't guarantee to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. In case if you're simply dumping elements from the `PriorityQueue` into a list, and then sorting this list, makes maintaining the `PriorityQueue` pointless.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Since I need to keep both the `PriorityQueue` and `List`, I was trying to find a more efficient way than to poll from the `PriorityQueue` to `List` and then offer back to the `PriorityQueue` while traversing the `List`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko It's not that I can't remove from the `PriorityQueue` but I would prefer to avoid it since it isn't efficient while keeping both.

Comment: Then adding to a list, and sorting it afterwards is your only option.

Comment: @dalawh Why can't you store these objects in a list a the first place? And do understand that maintaining an ordered collection, like PrioryQueue has a **cost** - adding each a new element into the queue will happen in **O(n)**, meanwhile adding an element into a list will done almost instantly, in **O(1)**. There's no point to populate a PrioryQueue if you cant remove elements from it.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the JavaDoc for `PriorityQueue`:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

It seems like an odd scenario to have to do this. You may want to review your use case and ensure you're using the best solution. You could use a `TreeSet` instead instead of a `List`, for example. Or you might need to rethink what you're trying to do with your queue in the first place.

But to answer your question, a pretty straightforward (but maybe not efficient?) way to copy a `PriorityQueue`'s prioritized elements into a `List` would be:

```
PriorityQueue<T> pq = ...
List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>(pq);
Collections.sort(myList, pq.comparator());
```

Comment: @AndyThomas it is my opinion and doesn't belong in my answer. I'll remove it.

Comment: In addition, a queue does not necessarily have a comparator.

Comment: @AndyThomas if there is no comparator, it will return `null`, and providing `null` to `Collections.sort` will instead use natural ordering, which is what the queue would be using if it returned `null` in the first place. So either way, the sorting behavior is the same between the two.